# how to display data from database into an option tag html?

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

any one can help me with this?
i want to displaying my database data into a option tag but it not showing anything. i have try to make a code for that but that code not work to display my data into html option tag. someone please help me to solve my problem.

this is my code that i make

```js
// JavaScript Document
// for make the option tag
$(function() {

$('#chkveg').multiselect({

includeSelectAllOption: true

});
});

// for call the data from my database
$(document).on('click','#nama_check',function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../php/absen/absen_karyawan_autocomplete.php",
        success: function(data){
            var list = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
                $('#chkveg').val((list[i]['bagian']));


            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>


<form id="form1" method="post">

        <div style="padding:20px">

        <select id="chkveg" multiple="multiple">
        </select>

        </div>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly to add values to the `select` you need to append new `option` elements to it, not repeatedly set the `val()`. Secondly, you should call `multiselect()` after the options have been added.

Also note that you can place all code within a single document.ready handler. Try this:

```
$(function() {    
  $(document).on('click','#nama_check',function(e){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../php/absen/absen_karyawan_autocomplete.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) { 
        var html = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          html += '<option>' + data[i]['bagian'] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#chkveg').html(html).multiselect({
          includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: still not working.. <Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined>
at `' + list[i]['bagian'] + '

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. `list[i]` should have been `data[i]`. I updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Use .append(). 
Try to check this documentataion: http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
        var list = JSON.parse(data);
        for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
            $('#chkveg').append($('<option>'+ list[i]['bagian']  +'</option>'));


        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: still not working.. <Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined> at `' + list[i]['bagian'] + '